# Regex matching for structured JSON items

Tags: javascript, json, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having an issue where I am trying to take a long multi-line string, use a bunch of regex replaces to make it (close to, but not perfectly) JSON format, before regex extracting elements.

The string is a raw whois data pull from a domain, I am trying to get things like the expiration date, etc. (Whois has lots of nuance which I am going to omit, like the 1200+ whois servers for different TLDs, each with different formats, etc.)

My function seems to work for a single domain, but when I use the function in a for loop, I am getting really erratic results. I am not sure if this is related to some kind of regex limit or something in apps scripts or if I have something out of place.

**Example String after initial processing:**

#### (var newString = )

> {"DomainName":"WANITAMALAS.COM","RegistryDomainID":"2115163838_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN","RegistrarWHOISServer":"whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com","RegistrarURL":"www.publicdomainregistry.com","UpdatedDate":"2019-04-14T10:02:49Z","CreationDate":"2017-04-17T15:35:40Z","RegistryExpiryDate":"2020-04-17T15:35:40Z","Registrar":"PDRLtd.dbaPublicDomainRegistry.com","RegistrarIANAID":"303","RegistrarAbuseContactEmail":"abuse-contact@publicdomainregistry.com","RegistrarAbuseContactPhone":"+1.2013775952","DomainStatus":"clientTransferProhibitedicann.orgepp#clientTransferProhibited","NameServer1":"BAYAN.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM","NameServer2":"LORNA.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM","DNSSEC":"unsigned","URLoftheICANNWhoisInaccuracyComplaintForm":"www.icann.orgwicf",">>>Lastupdateofwhoisdatabase":"2019-05-06T13:55:16Z<<<","FormoreinformationonWhoisstatuscodespleasevisiticann.orgepp","NOTICE":"Theexpirationdatedisplayedinthisrecordisthedatethe","registrar'ssponsorshipofthedomainnameregistrationintheregistryis","currentlysettoexpire.Thisdatedoesnotnecessarilyreflecttheexpiration","dateofthedomainnameregistrant'sagreementwiththesponsoring","registrar.Usersmayconsultthesponsoringregistrar'sWhoisdatabaseto","viewtheregistrar'sreporteddateofexpirationforthisregistration.","TERMSOFUSE":"YouarenotauthorizedtoaccessorqueryourWhois","databasethroughtheuseofelectronicprocessesthatarehigh-volumeand","automatedexceptasreasonablynecessarytoregisterdomainnamesor","modifyexistingregistrations;theDatainVeriSignGlobalRegistry","Services'(\"VeriSign\")WhoisdatabaseisprovidedbyVeriSignfor","informationpurposesonlyandtoassistpersonsinobtaininginformation","aboutorrelatedtoadomainnameregistrationrecord.VeriSigndoesnot","guaranteeitsaccuracy.BysubmittingaWhoisqueryyouagreetoabide","bythefollowingtermsofuse":"YouagreethatyoumayusethisDataonly","forlawfulpurposesandthatundernocircumstanceswillyouusethisData","to":"(1)allowenableorotherwisesupportthetransmissionofmass","unsolicitedcommercialadvertisingorsolicitationsviae-mailtelephone","orfacsimile;or(2)enablehighvolumeautomatedelectronicprocesses","thatapplytoVeriSign(oritscomputersystems).Thecompilation","repackagingdisseminationorotheruseofthisDataisexpressly","prohibitedwithoutthepriorwrittenconsentofVeriSign.Youagreenotto","useelectronicprocessesthatareautomatedandhigh-volumetoaccessor","querytheWhoisdatabaseexceptasreasonablynecessarytoregister","domainnamesormodifyexistingregistrations.VeriSignreservestheright","torestrictyouraccesstotheWhoisdatabaseinitssolediscretiontoensure","operationalstability.VeriSignmayrestrictorterminateyouraccesstothe","Whoisdatabaseforfailuretoabidebythesetermsofuse.VeriSign","reservestherighttomodifythesetermsatanytime.","TheRegistrydatabasecontainsONLY.COM.NET.EDUdomainsand","Registrars.",""}

**My function:**

```
function processAllDomains(){
    //Bunch of Sheets stuff here...//
    for(var i = 0 ; i< urlsList.length ; ++){
        whoisDataLookup(urlsList[i],"-"); // Second argument "Status" can be an error from a previous step in the process
    }
    //Do stuff//
}
function whoisDataLookup(domain,status) {
    var whoisData = [domain, status];

    whoisData.push(new Date());
    var CAYKwhoIsServer = "https://myHerokuWhoisApp.com/";

    var regexChecks = [];
    var Registrar = /(?:Registrar|RegistryDomainID|SponsoringRegistrar)":"(.*?)",/gim
        regexChecks.push(Registrar);

    var RegistrarURL = /(?:RegistrarWHOISServer|RegistrarURL)":"(.*?)",/gim
        //  var RegistrarWhoisUrl = /RegistrarWHOISServer":"(.*?)",/gi
        regexChecks.push(RegistrarURL);

    var UpdatedDate = /(?:UpdatedDate|Lastupdatedon)":"(.*?)",/gim
        regexChecks.push(UpdatedDate);

    var CreationDate = /(?:CreationDate|created|RegistrationTime)":"(.*?)",/gim
        regexChecks.push(CreationDate);

    var RegistryExpiryDate = /(?:RegistryExpiryDate|paid-till|ExpirationTime)":"(.*?)",/gim
        regexChecks.push(RegistryExpiryDate);

    var NameServer1 = /NameServer1":"(.*?)",/gim
        regexChecks.push(NameServer1);

    var NameServer2 = /NameServer2":"(.*?)",/gim
        regexChecks.push(NameServer2);

    var DNSSEC = /DNSSEC":"(.*?)",/gim
        regexChecks.push(DNSSEC);

    var fetchURL = CAYKwhoIsServer + domain;
    Logger.log('fetchURL is: ' + fetchURL);
    if (status != "-") { // If not null mark, then an error exists, so null the whole row
        for (var d = 0; d < regexChecks.length + 2; ++d) {
            whoisData.push("-")
        }
        return whoisData;
    }

    var whoisFetch = UrlFetchAppCacheToDrive(fetchURL, domain + "--whois") // just a url fetch, but saves the fetched content to Google drive, then if the same url is requested in future, pull the drive content, instead of fetching it from the web again.
        //    Logger.log('whoisFetch is: ' + whoisFetch);
        var whoisJSON = JSON.parse(whoisFetch);
    // Logger.log(whoisJSON.keys);


    var whoisString = JSON.stringify(whoisJSON["result"]); // the whois pulls other stuff, only the result is the actual whois string
    //   Logger.log('whoisString is: ' + whoisString);
    if (whoisString == undefined) {
        whoisString = "-";
    }

    whoisData.push(whoisString);

    try {
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/ /g, '');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/\,/g, '');

        if (whoisString.match("WhoisdServerVersion")) {
            whoisString = whoisString.replace(/.*WhoisdServerVersion/, '"WhoisdServerVersion');
            whoisString = whoisString.replace(/\(.*\)/, '');

        }
// Start a bunch of whois string cleanup, working towards the sample string shown above.
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/.*\(\w\:\)/, '$1');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/\%/g, '');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/\\r/gi, '');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/\\n\\n/g, '\\n');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/\\n\\n/g, '\\n');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/\\n\\n/g, '\\n');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/\\n$/, '');
        //    Logger.log('whoisString Check is: ' + whoisString);
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/https?:\/\//gi, '');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/\//gi, '');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/(\d\d)\:/gi, "$1qqqqqqqqqq"); // temporarily replace some COLON (:), to be sure we do not split up the string based on IPV6 ip addresses, which sometimes appear in whois string.
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/NameServers?:/i, 'NameServer1:');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/NameServer:/i, 'NameServer2:');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/NameServer:/i, 'NameServer3:');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/NameServer:/i, 'NameServer4:');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/NameServer:/i, 'NameServer5:');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/NameServer:/i, 'NameServer6:');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/NameServer:/i, 'NameServer7:');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/NameServer:/i, 'NameServer8:');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/:/g, '":"');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/":"\\n/g, '":"');
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/qqqqqqqqqq/gi, ":");
        whoisString = whoisString.replace(/\\n/gi, '","');
        // whoisString = whoisString.replace(/,""$/,'');


        var newString = "{" + whoisString + "}";



    } catch (e) {
        whoisData.splice(1, 1, "WhoisLookupError")
    }
    if (newString) {
        whoisData.push(newString);
    } else {
        whoisData.push('-')
    }
// **Everything seems to work as expected to this point, as my output shows 
// newString properly in all cases, from here, it gets wonky though.**

    for (var e = 0; e < regexChecks.length; ++e) {
        Utilities.sleep(50)
        var regexCheck = regexChecks[e];
        //  Logger.log('regexCheck is: ' + regexCheck);
        var metric = regexCheck.exec(newString);

        if (metric != undefined) {
            Logger.log(regexCheck + ' metric found is: ' + metric[1]);
            whoisData.push(metric[1])
        } else {
            Logger.log(regexCheck + ' metric not found');

            whoisData.push('-');
        }
    }
    return whoisData;

}
```

[image: Example Output showing erratic regex matching, when values exist and when regex101.com shows the regex should have matched.]

Here is an example of a single regex match, which logged as undefined:
(am not really worried about multiple matches, just need something in the field for now)
[image: Here is an example of a single regex match, which logged as undefined]

Comment: I don't see where in the picture the `undefined` are.

Comment: Sorry, I am using "-" as an undefined marker, my apologies, that should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would continue the road to make it valid JSON. The string that you have given is valid JSON except for one recurring pattern:

Some long string literals seem to be split into several string literals separated by commas. If you could just wrap those series into square brackets, they would form a valid array.

Here is how that would work:

```js
// The string you provided in the question:
var newString = `{"DomainName":"WANITAMALAS.COM","RegistryDomainID":"2115163838_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN","RegistrarWHOISServer":"whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com","RegistrarURL":"www.publicdomainregistry.com","UpdatedDate":"2019-04-14T10:02:49Z","CreationDate":"2017-04-17T15:35:40Z","RegistryExpiryDate":"2020-04-17T15:35:40Z","Registrar":"PDRLtd.dbaPublicDomainRegistry.com","RegistrarIANAID":"303","RegistrarAbuseContactEmail":"abuse-contact@publicdomainregistry.com","RegistrarAbuseContactPhone":"+1.2013775952","DomainStatus":"clientTransferProhibitedicann.orgepp#clientTransferProhibited","NameServer1":"BAYAN.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM","NameServer2":"LORNA.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM","DNSSEC":"unsigned","URLoftheICANNWhoisInaccuracyComplaintForm":"www.icann.orgwicf",">>>Lastupdateofwhoisdatabase":"2019-05-06T13:55:16Z<<<","FormoreinformationonWhoisstatuscodespleasevisiticann.orgepp","NOTICE":"Theexpirationdatedisplayedinthisrecordisthedatethe","registrar'ssponsorshipofthedomainnameregistrationintheregistryis","currentlysettoexpire.Thisdatedoesnotnecessarilyreflecttheexpiration","dateofthedomainnameregistrant'sagreementwiththesponsoring","registrar.Usersmayconsultthesponsoringregistrar'sWhoisdatabaseto","viewtheregistrar'sreporteddateofexpirationforthisregistration.","TERMSOFUSE":"YouarenotauthorizedtoaccessorqueryourWhois","databasethroughtheuseofelectronicprocessesthatarehigh-volumeand","automatedexceptasreasonablynecessarytoregisterdomainnamesor","modifyexistingregistrations;theDatainVeriSignGlobalRegistry","Services'(\\\"VeriSign\\\")WhoisdatabaseisprovidedbyVeriSignfor","informationpurposesonlyandtoassistpersonsinobtaininginformation","aboutorrelatedtoadomainnameregistrationrecord.VeriSigndoesnot","guaranteeitsaccuracy.BysubmittingaWhoisqueryyouagreetoabide","bythefollowingtermsofuse":"YouagreethatyoumayusethisDataonly","forlawfulpurposesandthatundernocircumstanceswillyouusethisData","to":"(1)allowenableorotherwisesupportthetransmissionofmass","unsolicitedcommercialadvertisingorsolicitationsviae-mailtelephone","orfacsimile;or(2)enablehighvolumeautomatedelectronicprocesses","thatapplytoVeriSign(oritscomputersystems).Thecompilation","repackagingdisseminationorotheruseofthisDataisexpressly","prohibitedwithoutthepriorwrittenconsentofVeriSign.Youagreenotto","useelectronicprocessesthatareautomatedandhigh-volumetoaccessor","querytheWhoisdatabaseexceptasreasonablynecessarytoregister","domainnamesormodifyexistingregistrations.VeriSignreservestheright","torestrictyouraccesstotheWhoisdatabaseinitssolediscretiontoensure","operationalstability.VeriSignmayrestrictorterminateyouraccesstothe","Whoisdatabaseforfailuretoabidebythesetermsofuse.VeriSign","reservestherighttomodifythesetermsatanytime.","TheRegistrydatabasecontainsONLY.COM.NET.EDUdomainsand","Registrars.",""}`;

// Turn the series of string literals into arrays of strings:
var json = newString.replace(/":\s*("(?:\\.|[^"])*"(?:,\s*"(?:\\.|[^"])*")+)(?!\s*:)/g, '": [$1]');

// Parse
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj);
```

Some of the key/values look a bit strange, as they just seem part of a longer text of which white space was removed. Possibly you could get better results if you would treat the (unknown) original string differently. But this object will at least allow you to easily extract what you need:

```
console.log(obj.DomainName);
console.log(obj.UpdatedDate);
// ...
```

Comment: This is really good advice. Thank you!
I had started this whole thing with hopes of getting to a valid JSON object, but there are many many variations on how the original raw string is provided that I was struggling to get it to a valid format. I'll give this a whirl now and see how it goes!

Comment: That last Regex Cleanup did indeed get me to the finish line. Thank you for your insight and help!